# Is possible using Plupload to resize the file for more sizes?

Tags: javascript, plupload

I need to upload certain file sizes using `plupload`. For example, small, medium and big picture .

Is possible do that with only javascript?

Comment: No- JavaScript alone cannot do it! But ploadload can do it using the flash/gears plugins. You can tell it how to resize and what quality on the client before it uploads. [Please read the docs more in depth how to do it.](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php)

Comment: @ppumkin Even by the time you wrote that post, Plupload was already able to resize images on the client side. Therefore, in theory, it would be possible to repeat that method for more than one image size. Still trying to figure that out though. Server side is easier.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Plupload does not use pure JS to do it but injects a proxy like silverlight, flash or something that has the API to manipulate images, save the new file. Then pluplaod uplaods the new file.

Comment: @ppumkin I always thought that, when you're using HTML5 (only), plupload would leverage a canvas element to do the image resizing on the client side before uploading the whole image to the server.

Comment: Yea- When I was working on pluplaod at the time there was no canvas implementation yet. But- It does make sense and its the fastest and safest way too :) But still. It is not JavaScript doing it but the browsers sandboxed libraries. You just use JS to tell it what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a function to resize image when it is uploaded.

```
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
// Strip the temp .part suffix off 
rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
resize_image($filePath);
}
```

Comment: I quote "Is possible do that with only javascript?". This isn't really javascript, is it? But I must add that it will probably be best to resize the images server side.

Answer (score 0):

**No. JavaScript is scripting language only.**

*It has not libraries to help manipulate things like images, copy files, send emails, etc .. We can invoke server side utilities or injected proxies but it was invented specifically for DOM manipulation*

In the question OP was specifically looking at using JavaScript to manipulate the image and use plupload to upload it. This in impossible because JS on its own cannot do that.

The default plugins for plupload rely on either silverlight, flash or gears and respectively those platform can manipulate images locally and then call upload with the resized file- which will upload to the server.

Possibly OP at the time I wanted to avoid flash, silverlight etc to keep cross browser compatibility and for use on old browsers.

So  a good solution is to uplaod the file to the server and use .NET/PHP tools to manipulate the images the way it was needed. While retaining the original image. It works well and you can restrict image sizes to 5mb; which can cause some bas user experience but that is a good trade off.